# SwiftUI: double-click in Table row on macOS

Tags: swiftui, macos-monterey

I am using a Table with multiple columns (new in SwiftUI 3.0) to show my data, and I want to be able to double-click on the row to open a new window with another view (with information passed in through the row that was double-clicked). What's the simplest way to achieve that? I can't seem to find any way to handle double-click on a selected row.

This is my current code to display the table:

```
      Table(item, selection: $selection, sortOrder: $sorting) {
            TableColumn("RecordName") { itemModel in
                Text("\(itemModel.recordName ?? "no name")")
            }
            TableColumn("Model") { item in
                Text("\(item.deviceName ?? "no model")")
            }
            TableColumn("CreatedAt") { item in
                Text("\(item.deviceCreatedDate?.formatted() ?? "no date")")
            }
      }
```

How do I handle a double-select action? Also, how do I open another view in another "window"?

Comment: Seems like this thread could be helpfull:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67978340/swiftui-3-macos-table-single-selection-and-double-click-open-sheet

Answer (score 1):

Apple introduced a new context menu modifier [contextMenu(forSelectionType:menu:primaryAction:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/equatableview/contextmenu(forselectiontype:menu:primaryaction:)?changes=latest_beta) with SwiftUI 4 at WWDC 2022. With this, a `primaryAction` can be provided that is performed when the user double clicks on a `Table` row.

```
@State private var selection: ItemModel.ID?

var body: some View {
    Table(items, selection: $selection, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
        TableColumn("RecordName", value: \.recordName)
        TableColumn("Model", value: \.model)
        TableColumn("CreatedAt", value: \.createdAt)
    }
    .contextMenu(forSelectionType: ItemModel.ID.self) { items in
        // ...
    } primaryAction: { items in
        // This is executed when the row is double clicked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the onTapGesture with the count of 2 is actually handling double clicking.
Here is a simplified example.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  SUITable
//
//  Created by Hezi Shahmoon on 10/02/2022.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items: [ItemModel] = Array(0...100).map { ItemModel(id: $0, recordName: "item \($0)", age: $0) }
    @State private var selection = Set<ItemModel.ID>()
    @State private var sorting = [KeyPathComparator(\ItemModel.age)]
    
    @State private var showingAlert = false
     
    var body: some View {
        Table(items, selection: $selection, sortOrder: $sorting) {
               TableColumn("RecordName") { itemModel in
                   Text("\(itemModel.recordName)")
                       .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: {
                           showingAlert = true
                       })
                       .alert("Important message", isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                                   Button("OK", role: .cancel) { }
                       }
               }
         }
    }
}

struct ItemModel: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var recordName: String
    var age: Int
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this just puts the 'tap' gesture on the text field in the first column. If you have multiple columns, you have to add this to each text field in each column! It also makes selection difficult.  Is there no way to add that to the whole table row?